# Expression resolves to an unused function (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programming and need bit of your help forgive me if i am asking something stupid. I am trying call a function from my UIViewController for a POST request to API. Calling function is like this

```
    @IBAction func actionStartSignIn(sender: AnyObject) {
            let email: String = txtEmail.text!
            let password: String = txtPassword.text!
            if !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty && General.isValidEmail(email) && password.characters.count>6{
                var request = RequestResponse()
                request.email = email
                request.password = password
                let isValid = NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(request)
                print(isValid)
                var requestBody: String = ""

                // Facing issue in following line
              RequestManager.sharedInstance.postRequest(Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.LOGIN, body: requestBody, onCompletion:  {(json: JSON) in{
                            let result = json["response"]
                            print(result)

                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```

And Called Function is like this

```
func postRequest(route: String, body: String, onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
        makeHTTPPostRequest(route, requestBody: body, onCompletion: { json, err in
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
    }
```

Further,

```
// MARK: Perform a POST Request
    private func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, requestBody: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

        // Set the method to POST
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        do {
            // Set the POST body for the request
            // let jsonBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: .PrettyPrinted)
            // request.HTTPBody = jsonBody
            request.HTTPBody = requestBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                if let jsonData = data {
                    let json:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)
                    onCompletion(json, nil)
                } else {
                    onCompletion(nil, error)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }/*  catch {
            // error
            onCompletion(nil, nil)
        }*/
    }
```

and

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void
```

I am facing "Expression resolves to an unused function" while calling

```
 RequestManager.sharedInstance.postRequest(Constants.BA‌​SE_URL + Constants.LOGIN, body: requestBody, onCompletion: {(json: JSON) in{ let result = json["response"] print(result) } } )
```

May be i am missing some basic syntax. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Where is your question? Which issue did you encountered?

Comment: Expression resolves to an unused function.
While Calling 
<code>RequestManager.sharedInstance.postRequest(Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.LOGIN, body: requestBody, onCompletion:  {(json: JSON) in{
                            let result = json["response"]
                            print(result)

                        }
                    }
                )</code>

Comment: Please update it to your question.

Comment: @t4nhpt Updated my question.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `sharedInstance`?. I guess that is a method, not a property.

Comment: @t4nhpt No, it is just an object of RequestManager. static let sharedInstance = RequestManager()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `{ }` phase after the `in` will solve the problem.
It should look like this:

```
RequestManager.sharedInstance.postRequest(Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.LOGIN, body: requestBody, onCompletion:  {(json: JSON) in
                        let result = json["response"]
                        print(result)
                }
            )
```

For the closure param, you should not type it by yourself to prevent typo. Use `tab key` to select that param, then press enter, xCode will auto generate the code for you.

If use the way I just said, the trailing closure will look like this:

```
RequestManager.sharedInstance.postRequest(Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.LOGIN, body: requestBody) { (json) in
                        let result = json["response"]
                        print(result)
                }
```

Comment: ohh.. Thank you.

as my guess was "SYNTAX" error.. :(
Sorry i am from JAVA background facing a difficult time in Swift Closures.

Thanks for your Time. :)

Comment: @t4nhpt great answer! thank you very much! save a lot of time.